# Getting the wrong output for perl script.

Tags: perl, windows-8.1

I've been trying to figure out how to run this example for a while now and I'm still stuck on how to print the date. Below is the example I'm working on.

```
(The Script for Unix/Linux)
# Backquotes and command substitution
1   print "The date is ", 'date';      # Windows users: 'date /T'
2   print "The date is 'date'", ".\n"; # Backquotes treated literally
3   $directory='pwd';                  # Windows users: 'cd'
4   print "\nThe current directory is $directory.";

(Output)
1   The date is Mon Jun 25 17:27:49 PDT 2007.
2   The date is 'date'.
4   The current directory is /home/jody/ellie/perl.
```

This is my work and output.

```
print "The date is ", 'date /T';
print "The date is 'date'", ".\n"; 
$directory='cd';
print "\nThe current directory is $directory.";  

(Output)
The date is date /TThe date is 'date'.
The current directory is cd.
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
print "The date is ", `date /T`;
print "The date is ", `date`, ".\n"; 
$directory=`cd`;
print "\nThe current directory is $directory.";
```

Comment: Because a similar issue discouraged me from programming when I first tried it as a kid, I'll add this advice: the [backtick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick) on a US keyboard is the button below ESC. On other layouts, it might be harder to find. On e.g. a German one, it's the button left of backspace, which you have to press while holding shift, and then pressing space as it's intended as a [diacritical mark called grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Grave_accent) that can also be put on a letter, like `è`. If that doesn't help, copy it from here: `\``

Comment: or use `qx()` which is easier to type and may even look nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a good explanation of what you're doing wrong (using single quotes instead of backticks or `qx(...)`) but it's probably worth pointing out that you don't need to call external programs in either of the two cases in your examples.

To get the current date, just call `localtime` in scalar context.

```
print scalar localtime;
```

For more complex date and time handling see [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

To get the current directory, use [Cwd](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd).

```
use Cwd;

print getcwd;
```

Not running unnecessary external programs is a good idea for two reasons. Firstly it makes your code more portable, and secondly it's more efficient (external programs are run in a new shell environment - and starting one of those is a relatively expensive operation).